# Sending an email with PHP/Javascript submit button

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, email, variables

I will try and be brief. When a user selects items in a checkbox, I want them to be able to press a submit button and it will send an email of the ingredients to a static email address. I am trying to store the values of the check boxes in an array called **finalOrder**, and have that array in the contents of the email.

I am fairly new to both languages, can I use the submit button to call the PHP code? Is the PHP written correctly? I am not too sure how to go about this.

Here is what I have so far.

```
<div>
 <input type="checkbox" name="foodType" data-name="Chicken Thighs">  <label 
 for="chickenThighs">Chicken Thighs</label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="foodType" data-name="Chicken Breast">  <label 
 for="chickenBreast">Chicken Breast</label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="foodType" data-name="Chicken Leg">  <label 
 for="chickenLeg">Chicken Leg</label>
 </div>


 <div id='results'>

 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 var finalOrder = [];

 document.querySelectorAll('input[name=foodType]').forEach(elem => {
    elem.addEventListener('change', updateList);
  });

  function buildList ()
  {
  let list = '<ul>';

  finalOrder.forEach(str => {
  list += "<li>" + str + '</li>';   
  });

 list += '</ul>';

 return list;
     }


function updateList ()
{
finalOrder = []; // Reset this array so that we can populate it with the new checkbox answers.

document.querySelectorAll('input[name=foodType]').forEach(v => {
    if (v.checked) {
    finalOrder.push(v.dataset.name);
}
});

document.querySelector('#results').innerHTML = buildList();
}


</script>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

<?php
// the message
$msg = finalOrder;

// use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
$msg = wordwrap(finalOrder($msg,70));

// send email
mail("my@email.com","New Order",$msg);
?>
```

Comment: You forgot to mention what is the problem. Anyhow, unless you simplified code here, I don't see anything that would submit data back to the server

Comment: Sorry, I updated the post. I am fairly new to both languages and a little unorganized right now.

Comment: Yes, you can send a request using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

There is one thing, missing so far.

1. A form tags to help post the data for the server for processing by PHP language so the file has to be saved as a PHP file and HTML. In the snippet I saved it as thisFile.php.

You can also consider the approach stated by @jaaba

```html
 <div>
    <form method="POST" action="thisFile.php"> 
     <input type="checkbox" name="foodType" data-name="Chicken Thighs">  <label 
     for="chickenThighs">Chicken Thighs</label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="foodType" data-name="Chicken Breast">  <label 
     for="chickenBreast">Chicken Breast</label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="foodType" data-name="Chicken Leg">  <label 
     for="chickenLeg">Chicken Leg</label>
     </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

     <div id='results'>

     </div>

     <script type="text/javascript">
     var finalOrder = [];

     document.querySelectorAll('input[name=foodType]').forEach(elem => {
        elem.addEventListener('change', updateList);
      });

      function buildList ()
      {
      let list = '<ul>';

      finalOrder.forEach(str => {
      list += "<li>" + str + '</li>';   
      });

     list += '</ul>';

     return list;
         }


    function updateList ()
    {
    finalOrder = []; // Reset this array so that we can populate it with the new checkbox answers.

    document.querySelectorAll('input[name=foodType]').forEach(v => {
        if (v.checked) {
        finalOrder.push(v.dataset.name);
    }
    });

    document.querySelector('#results').innerHTML = buildList();
    }


    </script>


    <?php
    // the message
    $msg = finalOrder;

    // use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
    $msg = wordwrap(finalOrder($msg,70));

    // send email
    mail("my@email.com","New Order",$msg);
    ?>
```